# How to solve systems of linear equations of multiple variables (more than 3 to 100s)?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

This was a question asked during an interview for programming job. And the bottom line was to write an alogrithm to solve such equations. As much as it numbed my neurons - it really provoked me. I had searched around for few days now. My maths knowledge is limited to freshman year. I am not sure if I am missing out sth from my limited maths knowledge. This whole multi variable concept looks like *prediction* system...or a *rule based* system.

Are there formal methods (*with fancy names*) available to solve linear equations of multi variables? Like new maths methods/theory I may have to learn. In what context are multi variable linear euqations used in real life? *Perhaps this could be trivia to you maths experts - pardon me if so.*

Comment: I mean, that's pretty much what linear algebra is all about. You put in all your independently linear equations/constraints in a matrix, and you solve using one of several different types of methods.

Comment: Google "numerical linear algebra" - a vast and specialized subject in its own right. Knowing standard linear algebra is necessary but only one of the ingredients that goes into the design of algorithms to solve large linear systems.

Comment: @user_of_math that wasn't my key word for search ;) I was searching the trivia : solving system of linear equations for multiple variables. Now that everyone is pointing out, I have to go start scratching liear algebra the *right way*!

Answer (score 1):

Row reduction is one of the classic methods and you can write software which will handle it. Although you would need a matrix library, which shouldn't be difficult to find.

An introductory text on linear algebra would be useful in understanding the techniques. As daOnlyBG mentioned, that's a large part of what linear algebra is about. I would write out a list of examples, but I am still not great with LaTex. [Here's](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/linearsystems/) an explanation that seems reasonable.

Gauss-Jordan elimination is a straight forward algorithm which can be implemented in code. Pseudocode from Wikipedia

```
 for k = 1 ... min(m,n):
   Find the k-th pivot:
   i_max  := argmax (i = k ... m, abs(A[i, k]))
   if A[i_max, k] = 0
     error "Matrix is singular!"
   swap rows(k, i_max)
   Do for all rows below pivot:
   for i = k + 1 ... m:
     Do for all remaining elements in current row:
     for j = k + 1 ... n:
       A[i, j]  := A[i, j] - A[k, j] * (A[i, k] / A[k, k])
     Fill lower triangular matrix with zeros:
     A[i, k]  := 0
```

Comment: Maths is geeky, your answer is a big relief. I will give it a try. Matrix seems like the way to go. Do you suggest any particular matrix library?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please write the examples on any editor you are familiar with and attach to your answer? I could possible convert it to LaTex.

Comment: I'll see if I can add it later, but the link that I gave does give an example and I also added pseudo-code for the algorithm, which I pulled from Wikipedia (should be alright though).

Comment: I still have a bit of a hard time understanding a matrix library and adapting one. Can you specify it a bit?